# Can you edit a CSHTML without building again

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a CSHTML file on the server. can I change part of the html code in the page without having ro rebuild my solution? Or everytime you edit the CSHTML you have to rebuild.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59304083/2509281

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to rebuild if you only change a Razor view. The changes will be automatically picked up.

Answer (score 2):

No, It is not required to build code for cshtml/vbhtml(razor view)  files.