# Build required for CSHTML changes, JS changes in ASP.NET MVC Core 3.1 Applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have recently upgraded my **ASP.NET MVC Core 2.2 application to Core 3.1**, everything works well, but in debug sessions if I make any changes to `CSHTML` file, like adding a new HTML tag or change code in JS file, it doesn't reflect by refreshing the app on localhost debug session. I will have to stop my VS and re-build and run in debug mode.

> This is happening only for ASP.NET Core 3.1 in other projects I have
>   with ASP.NET Core 2.2 for any CSHTML changes I don't have to rebuild
>   the solution.

I am using  `Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.4.1`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Found answer on SO: [.NET Core 3.0 - Preview 2 - Razor views don't automatically recompile on change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54600273/net-core-3-0-preview-2-razor-views-dont-automatically-recompile-on-change)

Install `NuGetpackage Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation`

update startup.cs with

```
services.AddControllersWithViews(x=>x.SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames = false)
.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```